# jquery cycle trough array, typeError undefined

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

i have a ajax function which return a json file and im pushing it to an array. i want to use the said array to cycle the NAME in that array. but im having an error of TypeError: names[(((+ index) + 1) % names.length)] is undefined. Can someone help me. thanks in advance.

```
var names = [];
var index = -1, looper, lastwinner;

$(document).on("click","#startraffle", function(){
    var majorprize = ($('#majorprize').is(":checked")) ? 1 : 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl+"/home/getparticipants/"+majorprize,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data.participants, function (id, value) {
                  names.push({name: value.name,  id:  value.id});
            });
        }
    }); 
    console.log(names);

    (function __cycle(){
        var name = names[++index % names.length].name;
        $("#winnername").text(name);
        looper = setTimeout(__cycle, 500);
    })();
    $(this).attr("disabled",true);
});
```

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. You are trying to cycle the array before it has been populated

Comment: what would be the best way to do it @charlietfl?

Comment: Either move the cycling into `success`...or make sure there is length before doing anything with the array

Comment: ohh see thats why when i clicked the button twice it start cycling.